# Selecting features with field not contained in all records of another field using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am quite new to QGIS 3.4.4 and it is complicated at times to get the proper thinking style.

I want to shift the location of some points in my vector layer.
I have a vector layer with points of waterbodies ("waterpoints") with a unique identifier field OBJECTID. I have another vector layer with some points which I relocated on the field. They have a field "Name" which refers to the OBJECTID.

I thought if I can delete all the original points whose "OBJECTID" is contained in "Name" of the other layer and thereafter merge the layers I would be fine. But I can´t make a selection or an export which can check that.

First I didn't manage to get the field from another layer, so I just merged them to run the expression within one layer.

I tried:

```
OBJECTID IN  (Name)
```

but it does not work...

I really don´t know how to proceed.
I would like to know how to properly write this expression or if there is an alternative method for relocating those points.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the QGIS version, but I will assume the newest one. In QGIS 3.6 in Processing you will find **Remove duplicates by attribute** algorithm. Link to [visual change log](https://www.qgis.org/pl/site/forusers/visualchangelog36/index.html#feature-new-algorithm-remove-duplicates-by-attribute)

[image: Remove duplicates by attribute]

Comment: You would first want to merge the two layers. Then you can run this algorithm to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Select by expression**, try the following in your **waterpoints** layer to select features where the `"OBJECTID"` value is found in the `"NAME"` field of the other layer. Let's assume your other layer is called `newlayer`.

`get_feature('newlayer','NAME',"objectid") IS NOT NULL`

This will check the column `NAME` in the layer `newlayer`, using the `"OBJECTID"` values from your current (=waterpoints) layer.

Please note the name of the *other* layer and its column are in *single quotes* and this is **case-sensitive**.

If it returns a feature (`IS NOT NULL`) then there is a match and these features will be selected. You can then delete these features.

You can also use the above expression in the field calculator, too, to generate a new column in your waterpoints layer (let's call it `dups`) which will return `1` if there is a match and `0` if there isn't. And delete all the features where there is a match (`"dups" = 1`).